# How do I change icon in AppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am just wondering what do I need to type here in "context". I just want when I click on sidedrawer that it opens that's it. But don't know what to type here...

[image]

Comment: You can pass the context you are receiving in your build method as argument. Check the parameter list of your build method.

Comment: But iconButton needs onPressed to work...i just don't know what to type in there where it says CONTEXT

Comment: Type `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()`. And check the documentation for that method as well

Comment: So what do I type if I just want my sidedrawer to work normally?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer

Comment: It does't help.

Comment: @slovenian_boy literally just type "context" like Midhun told you

Comment: yeah but when i press on it, it doesn't get me anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use GlobalKey:

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();

...

Scaffold(
  key: _key,
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      onPressed: () => _key.currentState!.openDrawer(),
```